# Ocurrió un error al crear la llave foránea

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones, modelorelacional

Estoy intentando crear una relación entre becarios y formador, al crear la llave foránea de becario y funciona pero al intentar crearla desde formador me sale el error de la imagen 1.

[image: estoy creando la relación entre esas dos tablas desde phpmyadmin y se lanza esa notificación de error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te estás indicando revises los tipos de datos, ambas columnas tienen el mismo tipo de dato?

Comment: Tienen el mismo tipo de dato, la misma longitud y el mismo motor innodb

Comment: Hazle un describe a tus tablas y añade el resultado a tu pregunta, ya que el error indica que no